# iPhoto backup on TimeCapsule using encrypted disk image

Tags: mac, backup, mount, iphoto

I have the following setup:

- Pics on my MBP
- Backups on my TimeCapsule
- iPhoto library alias pointing the real library on encrypted disk image

Every time I open iPhoto, it mounts the encrypted disk image. Once I close the iPhoto, it does the unmount.

Any ideas how I can get the iPhoto backups to work on TimeCapsule?